# What happened to me -- user suspended but docks my reputation repeatedly?

Tags: discussion

So I come on the site today to see even more reputation docked off without reason, and then in my small activity window it says "user was removed". This was nonetheless "UnbanRonMaimon", who actually started going on my other posts and randomly docking points -- I am currently at 996 but was at 1006, corresponding to 5 downvotes.

Do I just have to endure this?

[[Edit]]: There has been further reputation docked by someone else on a few of my answers just now, some sort of emotional attack. **This is outright inappropriate**. These include (just now):
1) [Can a system entirely of photons be a Bose-Einsten condensate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19127/can-a-system-entirely-of-photons-be-a-bose-einsten-condensate/19128#19128)
2) [With Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45653/newtons-third-law-why-does-anything-move-at-all/45656#45656)
3) [How can these fluid dynamical smoke-ring phenomena be explained?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46506/how-can-these-fluid-dynamical-smoke-ring-phenomena-be-explained/46518#46518)

Comment: I also lost some rep for the same reason.

Comment: I lost 18 because a user was removed. I do not know why you think it was "UnbanRonMaimon". I thought it was the rule that when a user is removed from the community for some reason the points he/she has given are deleted. Just checked "UnbanRonMaimon" is no longer a user. maybe he/she removed his/herself

Comment: Because he was the one docking the points when he was still active, I had a brief chat on one of my answers while he was doing it. And now he is no longer a user, i.e. under my answer his comments are listed as "user2963".

Comment: I'll ask someone on the team to have a look.

Comment: Many argumentative comments removed.

Comment: Of course, losing rep when a user is removed at their own request is [status-by-design]. I lost 60 in this most recent case. Easy come, easy go.

Comment: @dmckee: I see, thanks. My (implicit) ultimate concern is not the reputation lost on me, but the perception of the posts (due to random inappropriate downvoting) when other people view them in the future.

Comment: You were lucky, I lost 156 points when the user was removed!

Answer (score 4):

What happened is that a user got deleted (normally this happens by their own request).

All their recent votes, given within a set number of days are undone:

- if overall they gave you reputation, it is taken away
- if they overall took reputation from you, it is restored.

In my case, for example, I had (I assume) one up vote and two down votes from the user, giving me a +6 of reputation. Today I have a `-6 user was removed` message in my rep log.

Regarding the other 3 down votes, it looks like they are serial, however it's just three votes, I wouldn't get too upset about it :-)

Read more here:

[What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

And the obligatory "don't do that" post is here:

[Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Comment: Thank you for this information; further downvotes on my other posts accorded just before as well, right after I posted this meta-dicussion (some sort of disrespect), and there is nothing that can be apparently done for that.

Comment: @ChrisGerig: Oh, there is, don't worry. We are well aware of the situation, and are looking into it. If there are votes which need invalidating, this may take time (mods don't have the power to do that, we need to escalate it), but it will be done.

Comment: My case: I had 23 downs from the user. Now, I got +46. And, I know him. Coz, he's the one, who downvotes me each time. I think we all know him :-)